# MySQL update one table with a simple average based on another table's data

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with appName in common:

**table1:**

```
id, appName, mem
1,  app1,    2 
2,  app1,    4
3,  app2,    3
4,  app2,    5
```

**table2:**

```
id, appName, mem
1,  app1,    0 
2,  app2,    0
```

My goal is to update **table2** with a SQL query so that it has each app's running average like this:

**table2 (desired state):**

```
id, appName, mem
1,  app1,    3 
2,  app2,    4
```

Any ideas?
EDIT: by running average, I mean a simple average where it's a sum of mem divided by # of each app's records (i.e., app1 = sum(2,4) / 2))

Comment: What do you mean by "*running* average"?

Comment: I mean a sum of all mem values divided by count of records (i.e., app1 = sum(2,4) / 2))

Comment: what have you tried?  It is a basic requirement in SO that you have made some attempts at solving your own problem.  Describe those attempts and why they fail.  Or describe what searches you did to find information on how to update from querying another table, and why those search results did not help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This is what I've tried: `code`UPDATE table2 
SET avgMem = (SELECT AVG(table1.mem) AS `avgMem` FROM table1 LEFT JOIN appName app ON table1.appName = table2.appName WHERE table1.appName = table2.appName );

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table2, (SELECT app, AVG(mem) avg FROM table1 GROUP BY appName) t1avg SET table2.mem = t1avg.avg WHERE table2.appName = t1avg.appName;
```

Mind you, I haven't tested it, but that's the general format. You can create a subquery on an update to get this kind of data, though make sure to setup your indexes properly.

Also, you may want to consider a view if you're doing this often enough, and given it all, you should probably have apps in their own table, have a second table that has references to an appId and their memory.

Comment: Questions are supposed to show some effort to solve the problem, on the part of OP.  Answering questions that do not show what was attempted encourages bad questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Update table2 inner join table1 on table2.appName = table1.appName SET table2.mem = AVG (table1.mem) group by table1.appName
```

something like the above should work. Not tested as on phone currently

Comment: the question shows no effort to solve the problem.  Should we be answering it without that?

Comment: I can't test currently. The query should work. If there was an SQL fiddle I could try it

Comment: I assume you down voted because both answers are untested ?

Comment: I downvoted because the question shows no effort from OP to solve their own problem, no code, no searches.  I think answering questions like that encourages such bad behavior or at least fails to do what is best for OP - encourage them to figure out a very basic operation rather than have the answer handed to them.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work:

```
update table2 t2 join
           (select appname,avg(mem) as avgscore
            from table1
            group by appname
           ) t1
           on t1.appname = t2.appname
        set t2.mem = t1.avgscore;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6fa3c/1/1)